# Wrong item selection in ListBox (Windows Phone, Caliburn.Micro, Rx)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, system.reactive, caliburn.micro

I develop an app for Windows Phone 7 with using of Caliburn Micro and Reactive Extensions.

The app has a page with a `ListBox` control:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="12,0,12,0">
      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Views:ItemView Margin="0,12,0,0" />
              </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I'm using the next `ItemView` as a `DataTemplate`:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          cal:Message.Attach="[Event Tap] = [Action SelectItem]">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"
                   Text="{Binding Id}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the corresponding `ItemViewModel` looks like this:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public ItemViewModel(Item item)
    {
        Id = item.Id;
        Name = item.Name;

        _navigationService = IoC.Get<INavigationService>();
    }

    public void SelectItem()
    {
        _navigationService.UriFor<MainViewModel>()
            .WithParam(x => x.Id, Id)
            .Navigate();
        }
    }
}
```

The `ListBox` populates with items:

```
public class ListViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly IItemsManager _itemsManager;

    private List<ItemViewModel> _items;

    public List<ItemViewModel> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        private set
        {
            _items = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
        }
    } 

    public ListViewModel(IItemsManager itemsManager)
    {
        _itemsManager = itemsManager;
    }

    protected override void OnViewReady(object view)
    {
        base.OnViewReady(view);           

        Items = null;

        var list = new List<ItemViewModel>();

        _itemsManager.GetAll()
            .SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe((item) => list.Add(new ItemViewModel(item)), 
                (ex) => Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message), 
                () => 
                    {
                        Items = list;
                        Debug.WriteLine("Completed"));
                    }
    }
}
```

And here the problems begin.

`_itemsManager` returns all items correctly. And all items correctly displayed in the `ListBox`. There is ~150 items.

When I tap on an item then `SelectItem` method in the corresponding `ItemViewModel` must be called. And all works fine for first 10-20 items in `ListBox`. But for all the next items `SelectItem` method is called in absolutely incorrect `ItemViewModel`. For example, I tap on item 34 and `SelectItem` method is called for item 2, I tap 45 - method is called for item 23, and so on. And there is no no dependence between items.

I already head breaks in search of bugs. In what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was found after reading [the discussion forum](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/299193) and [the page in documentation](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation) of Caliburn.Micro. 
All problems were because of Caliburn.Micro's Conventions.

To solve the problem I've added to the `DataTempalate` the next code: `cal:View.Model={Binding}`. Now part of the page with the `ListBox` looks like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
      Grid.Row="1"
      Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Views:ItemView Margin="0,12,0,0" cal:View.Model={Binding}/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I think it's not a perfect answer. So I'll be glad if someone can provide better answer and explanation.